# Spring Boot Starter with Security - issue with Okta oauth2

Tags: spring, spring-security, okta

Looking for some help here.  We have a Spring boot web application, and trying to integrate Okta authentication.

We seem to have everything working... except, when the web.client attempts to grab the token from Okta, it's missing the "client_id" parameter in the body of the request to: https://xxxx.okta.com/oauth2/v1/token.

Cannot figure out #1, why it's missing, or #2, how to inject it.

This is a brand new project, all dependencies are 2021 Sept/Aug dates.

Anybody have any hints on what we might be missing?

Answer (score 0):

after hours and hours of digging - the best way to solve a problem is ask the question of the internet, then you find it.  Here it is:   spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.okta.client-authentication-method=post

Comment: Can you share what other configuration properties you were setting (not the actual values)? Were you creating an app that calls another REST service? 
If so any idea how the other REST service was set up? Was it another Spring Boot app?

I'd love to help make this process easier for other folks in the future!